# Netty: How to avoid receiving a file chunk and other messages in one BiteBuf

Tags: java, netty, file-transfer

I'm trying to send files via Netty. The file is sent and finally an "END FILE TRANSFER" message is sent in order to notify the client that the file has been send completely. This is the code:

```
File file = new File( "/file/to/pdf/test.pdf" );
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
ChannelFuture channelFuture = ctx.write(new DefaultFileRegion(raf.getChannel(), 0, raf.length())

channelFuture.addListener( new ChannelFutureListener(){
    @Override public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception{
        ctx.writeAndFlush( CommonClientDefines.END_FILE_TRANSFER.getBytes() );
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the last chunk of the file content and the "END FILE TRANSFER" message is received by the client in one `ByteBuf`.

```
public class FileChunkHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf>{
    @Override protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg) throws Exception{
    }
}
```

I guess this is because the incoming messages are also buffered on the client before forwarded to the channels in the pipeline. 
Any ideas how to solve this? Of course I could parse the messages for the end message, but if there's another solution I'd be interested to hear!

Comment: You have a poorly defined protocol. When using TCP, you'll always get a bunch of bytes. If you want to have data packets and other packets, you'll need to parse the bytes yourself.